# When is onAttachedToWindow called in the Layouting Process

Tags: android, android-layout, android-lifecycle

I'm not sure about the usage of `onAttachedToWindow`.

My question is basically about the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow%28%29).
Which mentions:

> [...] it may be called any time before the first onDraw --
>   including before or after onMeasure(int, int)

**I what to know:**

when it is called before `onMeasure` and when is it called after.

**The Story behind:**

I am adding `OnGlobalLayoutListener` in `onAttachedToWindow` and remove it in `onDetachedFromWindow`. Because is somehow logic to me to handle the layouting when the view is added to the window.
But I am concerned that the first onGlobalLayout calls get lost, if the Listener is not added yet. (because onMeasure usually happens during the layouting)

If someone got a better approach for my problem, feel free to give me a hint.

Comment: well.. the documentation explicitly mention that it have no set defined order. So I wonder if can't just use `OnPreDrawListener` instead, what way knowing for sure that every is layouted, ready and attache to window. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html

Comment: @Budius Thanks for the quick response. But isn't the `OnPreDrawListener ` called before every draw call? (At least more often than onGlobalLayout?)

Comment: yes it is called before every draw. But then you can `removeOnPreDrawListener` inside it. That would do to guarantee at least 1st call. You should still use `GlobalLayout` if you really need for every call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docs are correct, and you should not rely on `onWindowAttach/Detach` being in sync with `onMeasure` or `onLayout` pass.

If your `View` class is interested in parent hierarchy changes, I'd advice against such a design. The Parent UI should notify sub-views of hierarchy changes. So, `OnGlobalLayoutListener` better be used by an enclosing UI class.

Also, `View` class has [`onSizeChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) that you can override to detect when it has been measured up.

Comment: Thanks. I think thats the best answer I can get. I guess the way I used the OnGlobalLayoutListener in this cases, isn't the way it should be used.